# aiohttp: get current running app

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Currently I'm doing the following to get the current running app

```
async def handler(request):
    app = request.app
```

Isn't there another way for getting the current running app? Consider the below snippet (the `default` for `author_id`):

```
class Comment(DeclarativeBase):
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('member.id'), default=Member.current_logged_in()) 

class Member(DeclarativeBase):
    @classmethod
    def current_logged_in()
        pass
```

As the `session` is kept in the current running app and as you can see it is only accessible from the incoming `request`, how can I get the current running app to use the `session` for determining the `current_logged_in` user and thus be used as the `default` value for `Comment`'s `author_id`?
I wish I have made my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no implicit context for `aiohttp` application.

BTW don't do synchronous calls (`SQLAlchemy` ORM in your case) from `aiohttp` code.